# Looking to add L1 regularization to a quadratic minimization

Tags: convex-optimization, regularization

I'm hoping to minimize $\| y - Ax \|^2$ subject to a total variation constraint on the derivative of $x$ where $y$ is given. I'm hoping to use CVXOPT. I think I can set this up as follows:

$$
P = \min_x \frac{1}{2} \|y - Ax \|^2 + \epsilon |D x |_1
$$
aka
$$
P = \max_\mu \min_x \frac{1}{2} \|y - Ax \|^2 + \epsilon |z|_1 + \mu^t(Dx - z)
$$
which I break up as max of $P_1(\mu) + P_2(\mu)$ with
$$
P_1 (\mu) = \min_x \frac{1}{2} \|y - Ax \|^2 +  \mu^t Dx \quad \quad P_2(\mu) = \min_z \epsilon |z|_1  - \mu^t z
$$
The latter I see is $-\infty$ unless $| \mu |_\infty \le \epsilon$ in which case it is zero, but $P_1$ is slowing me down....

Is the following logic correct?

If $Ax = 0$ then I could make $\mu^t D x$ as negative as I wanted unless I could force that expression to be zero, i.e. that $\mu^t D$ is in kernel of $A$, i.e. $D^t \mu = A^t b$ for some $b$. If that constraint is satisfied then
$$
P_1 ( \mu ) = \frac{1}{2} (y^t - x^t A^t)(y - A x) + b^t A x
$$
which I differentiate to get $- y^t A + x^t A^t A + b^t A = 0$ and then wave hand in air a bit to say that must be the same as $Ax = y - b$. [Is that ok? I can assume $A A^t$ is invertible if it helps..] So the minimum becomes
$$
P_1 ( \mu ) = \frac{1}{2} y^t y - y^t (y-b) + \frac{1}{2} (y^t - b^t)(y-b) + b^t (y-b)
  = b^t y - \frac{1}{2} \| b \|^2
$$

Lastly, for the derivative operator, then $D D^t$ is invertible so $\mu = (D D^t)^{-1} D A^t b$ to give what I think is the final configuration:

$$
P = \max_\mu  b^t y - \frac{1}{2} \| b \|^2 \quad \text {where} \quad \| (D D^t)^{-1} D A^t b \|_\infty \le \epsilon
$$
which looks like something I can pass to CVXOPT. Does this make sense? That gets me $b$ and so $\mu$. **How do I get from $b$ to $x$?**

p.s. I see something in the CVXOPT about making special matrices to invert customized KKT matrix, or something, to speed things up, but I'm not there yet. I want to get the "basic" configuration working first.

Comment: Duh. A full row rank means $A.A^t $invertible so if $q^t.A$ = 0 then $q^t A.A^t=0$ so $q = 0$, but if the definition of full row rank is that if q^t A = 0 then q = 0, so either way there appears to be no issue about $Ax =y-b$. Wanted to comment before someone else did :-)

Comment: Problem. $\mu = (D D^t)^{-1} D A^t b$ says that $D^t \mu = A^t b + c$ for some constant vector $c$. So $D D^t \mu = D A^t b$ but that isnt quite what is required to keep $P_1$ away from $-\infty$.

Comment: Hmmm. CVXOPT documentation seems to want me to increase variables from $n$ for $x$ to add another $n-1$ for $z$, then minimize $1/2 \| y - Ax \|^2 + \epsilon \mathbf{1}^t z$ subject to component-wise $-z \le Dx \le z$. I would not have thought of that....

Comment: Yup. That did it. Everything worked, even the KKT stuff. All I had to do was modify the Total Variation example that came with the CVXOPT code to edit a matrix "S" in the KKTSOLVE with $A^t A + 4...$ instead of $I + 4...$. Blindingly fast even with 40,000 unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

So as noted in my comment. The best way to proceed is to add another unknown $z$ of dimension $n-1$  then minimize $1/2∥y−Ax∥^2+ϵ1^t z$ subject to component-wise
$−z ≤ Dx ≤ z$

This seems like it might be crazy inefficient but the corresponding KKT matrix has a very simple structure with lots of diagonals and tridiagonals so it can be inverted very quickly.